# flutter: Right overflowed by pixels

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is my code:

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
    leading: IconButton(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
    ),
  ),
  backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
  body: Visibility(
      visible: questionLoaded,
      child: Builder(builder: (context) {
        return Wrap(
          spacing: 8.0,
          runSpacing: 4.0,
          direction: Axis.horizontal,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Text(
                question!.question,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: GoogleFonts.mukta(
                  textStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.amber,
                      fontSize: 24,
                      shadows: const [
                        Shadow(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            offset: Offset.zero,
                            blurRadius: 15)
                      ]),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            if (question?.answer1 != "")
              RadioButton(
                textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                description: (question?.answer1)!,
                value: "1",
                groupValue: _decision,
                onChanged: (value) => setState(
                  () => _decision = value!,
                ),
              ),
            if (question?.answer2 != "")
              RadioButton(
                textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                description: (question?.answer2)!,
                value: "2",
                groupValue: _decision,
                onChanged: (value) => setState(
                  () => _decision = value!,
                ),
              ),
            if (question?.answer3 != "")
              RadioButton(
                textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                description: (question?.answer3)!,
                value: "3",
                groupValue: _decision,
                onChanged: (value) => setState(
                  () => _decision = value!,
                ),
              ),
            if (question?.answer4 != "")
              RadioButton(
                textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                description: (question?.answer4)!,
                value: "4",
                groupValue: _decision,
                onChanged: (value) => setState(
                  () => _decision = value!,
                ),
              ),
          ],
        );
      })),
);
```

This produces the following issue:

[image]

Any idea why and how can I fix it ?

Comment: Can you share the RadioButton reusable code?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your Text  widget `Flexible` or `Expanded` widget.

```dart
Expnaded( child: Text( question!.question,....
```

Comment: I think maybe you don't get it. As you can see I don't have a problem with the `Text` field. I have problem with the length of the `description` of the `RadioButton`

Comment: are using Text widget inside `RadioButton`? wrap that with Expanded, if it still fails, consider including necessary snippet to reproduce the issue

Comment: No as you can see.

Comment: my bad, 1 min I will test it bt Can you include your `RadioButton` including text that will reproduce the error ?

Comment: Just write a bit longer and it will be good enough to test.

Comment: Sorry, I am busy for it. someone may help

Answer (score -1):

If your text is wrapped in column then column should be wrapped expanded widget.

```
Expanded(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Text(
          'datadatadatadatadatadata',
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

But if your text is wrapped in a row then your text should be wrapped expanded widget.

```
Row(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Text(
          'datadatadatadatadatadata',
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: My issue is not with the text width.